# How can I prevent a blank UTM value from being passed in a form submission?

Tags: javascript, forms, utm

I am working in Pardot, if it matters, but have some javascript which will write GA utm parameters to hidden fields.

Unfortunately, if any of the values are blank, it will pass that blank value, and overwrite any existing value. **It's important that I am able to overwrite existing values**, but only when there is data in the query string.

Is it possible to write default values instead? So for example, a form is submitted with no utm_source, then we write Source="Organic", or something similar.

Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
// Parse the URL
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
// Give the URL parameters variable names
var source = getParameterByName('utm_source');
var medium = getParameterByName('utm_medium');
var campaign = getParameterByName('utm_campaign');
var campaign = getParameterByName('utm_content');

// Put the variable names into the hidden fields in the form. selector should be "p.YOURFIELDNAME input"
document.querySelector("p.source input").value = source;
document.querySelector("p.utm_medium input").value = medium;
document.querySelector("p.utm_campaign input").value = campaign;
document.querySelector("p.utm_content input").value = content;



</script>
```

Thank you so much for your insight!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you make the value `""` if empty, and since that is `false`y in javascript, just put an if statement before each of the 4 value statements:

`if (source) document.querySelector("p.source input").value = source;`

In long form, you are saying that if the value exists, then fill in the element with the value. Otherwise, don't do anything:

```
if (source) {
  document.querySelector("p.source input").value = source;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm struggling to get this to work. I hate to sound naive, but, well I am. What am I missing? `if (source) document.querySelector("p.utm_source input").value = source;
if (medium) document.querySelector("p.utm_medium input").value = medium;
if (campaign) document.querySelector("p.utm_campaign input").value = campaign;
if (content) document.querySelector("p.utm_content input").value = content; `

Comment: What you have written there looks good, so there must be something in the bigger picture that we are missing. Are you sure that your function `getParameterByName` works as you expect it? Can you link to a more complete version of your code, like by putting it on Pastebin? (remove any proprietary info before doing so) Also I re-read your original post and you accidentally define `var campaign` twice.

Comment: I caught that, too and updated it. Thank you. here's the pastebin:  https://pastebin.com/SPA376rx

Comment: It works for me. Here is what I did to test it: Remove the "hidden" class/type tags from the utm_campaign form field <p> and <input> elements so they are visible. I also  set `value` to "testing" so there would be something there already. Then I ran the html file through a local server and added the querystring `?utm_campaign=xxx` and hit that URL, and it showed xxx. I again hit the URL without the querystring and it shows "testing", so it did not overwrite it with a blank string. What problem are you facing exactly? (Also I verified that your original post indeed had the overwriting problem.)

Comment: Using your method I can see that it's working for me as well. Which tells me it is a platform problem which is causing the value to be overwritten. So, in that case, you have helped me tremendously. I just need to understand why the existing value is being overwritten by the platform. Thank you!